# Web scraping with BS4: unable to find tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

There is a site that provides football (soccer) related statistics, I find the in-house option of querying the data to be limiting and want to perform my own analysis, but to do so I must scrape the data - I am using Beautiful Soup 4.

Documentation is found [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree).

According to Beautiful Soup documentation I can search for a particular tag using `find_all()`, however when I try to use it it turns up for a blank.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv as csv 


    html = urlopen("http://members.fantasyfootballscout.co.uk/player-stats/goalkeepers/")
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "lxml")
```

Presumably, being behind a pay wall you will not be able to access it. With this in mind I will post code snippet.

```
 <tbody>
                                                                                                                                                                                        <tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="players[]" value="61302"></td>
           <td class="first"> 
<a href="/player-profiles/ryan-allsopp/" class="enhanced-title" title="Ryan Allsopp"> Allsopp </a>

 <div class="profile-title">
  <img src="/images/players/small/default.png" alt="" width="42" height="64">
            <br>Ryan Allsopp <br> (Bournemouth, Goalkeeper)
 </div>                            
</td>

 <td class="nowrap">
     <span class="team-disc bou-light"></span>
<a href="/player-stats/goalkeepers/fantasy-index/bournemouth/" title="Bournemouth"> BOU</a>
</td>
                                                                                                    <td title="Starts: 0">0</td>
                                                                                                                                    <td title="Time Played: 54"> 54</td>
                                                                                                                                    <td title="Subbed On: 1">1</td>
                                                                                                                                    <td title="Subbed Off: 0"> 0</td>
                                                                                                                                    <td title="Goals: 0"> 0 </td>
                                                                                                                                    <td title="Assists: 0"> 0 </td>
                                                                                                                                    <td title="Clean Sheets: 0">0 </td>
                                                                                                                                    <td title="Goals Conceded: 1">     1 </td>
                                                                                                                                    <td title="Own Goals: 0">   0 </td>
                                                                                                                                    <td title="Saves: 0">  0  </td>
                                                                                                                                    <td title="Premier League Yellow Cards: 0">  0</td>
                                                                                                                                    <td title="Premier League Total Red Cards: 0">  0 </td>
                                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                                                                                                                        <tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="players[]" value="57187"></td>
```

To start with I want to pull all the table data, but I am having trouble identify even one td in BS.

```
bsObj.td # returns empty set
bsobj.find_all('td') # returns empty set
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You mentioned a paywall. Are you sure your Python code can access this page? Did you try to `print(html.read())` ?

Comment: You should reformat your HTML text, it's very unreadble.

Comment: @OmarShehata it returned: b''

Comment: You have to login to access it so how do you expect it to work if you don't? Posting the html that you see in your browser  while you are logged in is not relevant to the problem at all

Comment: @PadraicCunningham when I send a request to the web server from Python it won't marry it up with my logged in session?

Comment: @Will, no, if it did I would be very worried. You will need to login and persist  the session cookies, I would recommend using a `requests.Session` http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

Comment: @...because you would want to authenticate each request attempt incase of someone with nefarious intentions cloned IP address for the session? (Not sure whether I am putting that in the right terms)

Comment: @Will, a lot of ips are dynamic so using just an ip address to persist a login would be a very  idea, even if it were static a lot of people could and most likely are on the same network so would you like anyone who shares your ip to access your sensitive data without needed to login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments above were helpful, I have persisted session cookies as suggested though that failed to solve the issue.

The solution relates to asynchronous HTTP calls made by the javascript portion of the site. I have installed selenium (documentation [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io)), which I will use to execute javascript, to give me access to the data that I want.